# Is it safe to use a monitor power adapter with a higher amperage?

Tags: display, power-supply

My MSI monitor power adapter gets hot when in use, and it's not even summer yet.

I'm worried about this 20V 2.25A power adapter; it looks tiny and cheap. I really want to change it with a used one I found, very robust and cheap ones for sale. But my only problem is the amperage; most of them are 65W 3.25A or more. Would this harm my new monitor?

Comment: Are you using the adapter that came OEM with the Monitor?

Comment: yes the box was sealed and a checked again on various websites it's the same adapter very cheap  and tiny for gaming monitor

Comment: So long as you use the same voltage and the same connection pins (for polarity), you can safely use a higher wattage adapter. No issue there.

Comment: Alright, Thank you so much!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It says on top of the question content that it **is** running hot, so maybe good advice for new users...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes while true, keep in mind that the term "hot" is different for everyone. Very warm is definitely acceptable, but can be considered hot to some, whereas so hot that it may burn you, hot, is an actual concern. Many power adapters get very warm, but they are within tolerances, so its acceptable to use this. They will still outlast the device 99 out of 100 times.